# Differences between methods for solving linear equation system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a huge linear equation system in this form:

F=K.Δ

as usual form of problems in the finite element method, where the F vector and K are known and Δ vector is unknown. There are several methods like Cholskey, QR and Gauss that can be used for solving the system to get the Δ. I know that there are some fundamental differences and limits to some of these methods, for example Cholskey is limited to symmetric matrices or some methods are limited to specific [matrix storage methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Storing_a_sparse_matrix). But as long as the K matrix in the equation above is symmetric i can use several methods also am able to assemble K with all storage formats.

I need to know what is the best method for solving such a sparse linear system regarding the methods speed. and what are factors that methods usually are chosen for problems.

Comment: There are many books written on specifically this subject.  Why ask somebody here to write another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find some quite good guidelines for choosing best sparse solving method here:

What guidelines should I follow when choosing a sparse linear system solver?
https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/81/what-guidelines-should-i-follow-when-choosing-a-sparse-linear-system-solver